# Span not fitting round input

Tags: css, html

The span will just not expand to the height of the text input, I just want them to be the same height. I don't know why it wont expand

The code - http://jsfiddle.net/8Jxsd/

```
input{
font-size: 28px;
border: none;
margin: 0;
}
#searchbox{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
outline: none;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px 0 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background-color: #FFF
}
#searchinput{
padding: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
#searchgo{
padding: 5px;
background-image: url(images/arrow.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width: 40px;
background-position: 0 -1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
text-indent: -500em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element by default. Change   inline  element to a block element by 
 display:inline-block;

Inline elements are displayed on the same line of the parent but each block level element will occur on next line with own width and height. we need the span be in same line and block so you can have inline-block property for display so that in same line the span will take own width height.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation was worth more than the answer!

Answer (score 0):

replace rule `font-size: 28px;` in selector `input {}` with rule `font-size: inherit;`

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block;` with `span` class

```
#searchbox{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jxsd/1/)